# ruby on rails, javascript block keeps loading in every page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I was doing a rails project and I added a small piece of 3rd party javascript which generated a button to my html.erb file in view, then I deleted it. However, the javascript (of course the button) keeps loading even if the source code didn't have that block. And more, whenever I created a controller/action, when I visit the page, the button will show up. Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without seeing the code/error.

But I would recommend either:

1. Removing the javascript gem.
2. Searching and deleting the javascript.